# New window opening while changing JPanel present in the JFrame on Click of Button

Tags: java, swing

I am making a project in netbeans whose GUI I am creating using swing.

I wanted to change the panels present in the frame when a button is clicked. For this to be achieved I am creating a class named Global which looks like this :

```
public class Global {
    public static void changePane (final JPanel p) {
        MainFrame f = new MainFrame();
        changePane(f, p);
    }
    public static void changePane(final JFrame f,final JPanel p){
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                f.getContentPane().removeAll();
                f.setContentPane(p);
                f.repaint();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
 }
```

So there is a `MainFrame` class which has the main method which looks like:

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    Global.changePane(new MainPanel());
}
```

And in the `MainFrame` there are few buttons / menuitems. The action performed method looks as follows

```
private void jMenuItem4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Global.changePane(new addworkload());
}
```

So when I am trying to replace the panel in the frame a new window opens. I want to prevent this from happening i.e. i want the panel to be replaced in the same window. Please help.

Comment: Your `changePanel(JPanel)` creates a new `JFrame` and shows that...don't do that.  Actually, instead, use a `CardLayout` and stop messing about with screwing with the frame...

Comment: Agreed to @MadProgrammer. I worked on a similar app, where navigation had to be done. Your best bet is using a `CardLayout` Here is a simple example of how to implement a `CardLayout`: http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/swing/cardlayout.html